# Line is rendering only vertical line instead of sloped line

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

Line is not rendering correctly. It's rendering as [image: incorrect] instead of [image: correct]

My code is as follows:

LineGraph.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';

function Linegraph() {
    return (
        <div className="linegraph">
            <Line
                data={{
                    datasets:[{
                        type:"line",
                        data:[{x:10,y:20},{x:15,y:10},{x:12,y:4}],
                        backgroundColor:"black",
                        borderColor:'#5AC53B',
                        borderWidth:2,
                        pointBorderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                        pointBackgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor:'#5AC53B',
                        pointHoverBorderColor:"#000000",
                        pointHoverBorderWidth:4,
                        pointHoverRadius:6,
                    }]
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Linegraph
```

I'm following a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxggrQ0nHjY) and at 1:33:17 they were successfully able to implement it while mine remained as the vertical line going straight down.

Here's also a screenshot of my project set-up:
[image: project set-up]

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up getting this to work by going inside `package.json` and setting the following versions:

```
'chart.js':'^2.9.4',
'react-chartjs-2':'^2.11.1'
```

=)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the chart `type` to `'scatter'` and add the property `drawLine: true` to the dataset.

```
datasets:[{
  type: "scatter",
  drawLine: true,
  data:[{x:10,y:20},{x:15,y:10},{x:12,y:4}],
  ...
```

> The Chart.js [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) states that scatter charts are based on basic line charts with the x axis changed to a linear axis.

Therefore, assuming you're using `react-chartjs-2` together with **Chart.js v3**, you may also keep `type: 'line'` but will have to define the x-axis as `type: 'linear'` as follows:

```
data={{
  type: "line",
  ...
}}
options={{
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: "linear"
    }
  }
}}
```